# Why are the integers being sent from one android app Activity to another causing my app to crash?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, integer

I've got a [DONE] button that's supposed to check 2 entries's results. One of them is an [EditText--inputType:number] and the other is a [TextView] that increments when a certain button is pressed.

What I'm trying to do is check whether the EditText has an integer or is null, and check the contents of the TextView. if they both are greater than Zero. I add them up and send the total to my main activity. Here's the code i have so far.

```
    public void returnbtn(View view) {

    // Initialize insert textView
    EditText insertcountBtn = findViewById(R.id.insertPushup);

    // Initialize counter textView
    TextView givencountBtn = findViewById(R.id.showCount);

    // get added int stuff from the insert textField
    int insertcountInt = 
    Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());

    // get string stuff from counter textView
    String givencountString = givencountBtn.getText().toString();

    // convert counter textView to int.
    Integer givencountInt = Integer.parseInt(givencountString);

    if (givencountInt <= 0 && insertcountInt <= 0){
        Total = 0;
    }  else if (givencountInt > 0 && insertcountInt <= 0) {

        Total = givencountInt;
    } else if (givencountInt <= 0 && insertcountInt > 0) {
        Total = insertcountInt;
    } else if (givencountInt > 0 && insertcountInt > 0){
        // Add Counter textView and Insert textView to an Int Total
        Total = givencountInt + insertcountInt;
    }

    // Create an Intent to return to the mainActivity.
    Intent beginPushup = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // Pass the current number to the push-up Counter activity.
    beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_DONE, Total);

    // Start mainActivity.
    startActivity(beginPushup);

}
```

The problem i'm having is with either textView or EditText i'm not sure. All i know is that if i fill them both and click done it adds them up and transfers the total to mainActivity as expected. If I add values to EditText and leave TextView with 0 it also does what it's meant to do. But if I increment TextView and leave EditText blank, it does not transfer my TextView integer and crashes app.

Could i be detecting the editText wrong, because i think that's the reason.
If so what's the right way?

----- First && Second Answer Edits -----

```
    int insertcountInt;
    String insertcountString = 
    String.valueOf(insertcountBtn.getText());

    try {
        insertcountInt = 
    Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());

        if (insertcountInt <= 0 || insertcountString == " ") Total = 
    givencountInt;
        if (insertcountInt > 0 ) Total = givencountInt + 
    insertcountInt;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        insertcountInt = 0;
    }
```

Good news is no more crash, but unless I fill the EditText with something, I'm not receiving my Integer in mainActivity. This is getting interesting. * I think it's a play of the if statements which I've restructures, but no luck so far. *

----- Updated Working Code For Any Future Requests -----

```
public void filledChecker() {

    // Initialize insert textView
    EditText insertcountBtn = 
    findViewById(R.id.insertPushup);

    // Initialize counter textView
    TextView givencountBtn = findViewById(R.id.showCount);

    int insertcountInt = 0;
    int givencountInt = 0;

    // get added int stuff from the insert textField
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(insertcountBtn.getText()) && 
    TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(insertcountBtn.getText())) {
        insertcountInt = 
    Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());
    }

    // get string stuff from counter textView
    String givencountString = givencountBtn.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(givencountString) && 
    TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(givencountString)) {
        givencountInt = Integer.parseInt(givencountString);
    }

    if (insertcountInt <= 0) {
        Total = givencountInt;
    }
    if (insertcountInt > 0) {
        Total = givencountInt + insertcountInt;
    }

}

public void returnbtn(View view) {
    // Create an Intent to return to the mainActivity.
    Intent beginPushup = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    filledChecker();
    Integer current_Id = getIntent().getIntExtra(GIVEN_ID, 0);

    // Pass the current number to the push-up Counter activity.
    if (current_Id == 1) beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_P_DONE,     
    Total);
    if (current_Id == 2) beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_S_DONE,     
    Total);
    if (current_Id == 3) beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_C_DONE,     
    Total);
    if (current_Id == 4) beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_SQ_DONE,    
    Total);
    beginPushup.putExtra(GIVEN_ID, current_Id);

    // Start mainActivity.
    startActivity(beginPushup);
}
```

I As you can see I ended up dividing the if-logic from the Intent to Transfer to main Activity. This way they're both simple. And using the Do Not Repeat Yourself i did the same thing to the rest of my other buttons as you can see with all the if's in [returnbtn] method. I also simplified the if statement aside from the ones i was helped with. I ended up needing 2 if statements to manage getting a total from the 2 entries. Thanks again for the help everyone. Ohh the try-except didn't seem necessary so i deprecated them. as the app gets more complex i'll add them if necessary.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. the crash happens when i'm running it on my virtual device. does that accurately respond to your question? or is there any other code you'd wanna see. i'm not sure where i can find an error log for such a crash.

Comment: All my gradle builds are perfectly bugless so to speak. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer explained, the issue with your code is that when the EditText is blank then parsing "null" is causing exception. So you just have to insure that if content is null then just use 0(Zero) value.
 You can try this:

```
public void returnbtn(View view) {

// Initialize insert textView
EditText insertcountBtn = findViewById(R.id.insertPushup);

// Initialize counter textView
TextView givencountBtn = findViewById(R.id.showCount);

int insertcountInt = 0;
int givencountInt = 0;

// get added int stuff from the insert textField
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(insertcountBtn.getText()) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(insertcountBtn.getText())) {
    insertcountInt = Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());
}

// get string stuff from counter textView
String givencountString = givencountBtn.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(givencountString) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(givencountString)) {
    givencountInt = Integer.parseInt(givencountString);
}

if (givencountInt <= 0 && insertcountInt <= 0){
    Total = 0;
}  else if (givencountInt > 0 && insertcountInt <= 0) {

    Total = givencountInt;
} else if (givencountInt <= 0 && insertcountInt > 0) {
    Total = insertcountInt;
} else if (givencountInt > 0 && insertcountInt > 0){
    // Add Counter textView and Insert textView to an Int Total
    Total = givencountInt + insertcountInt;
}

// Create an Intent to return to the mainActivity.
Intent beginPushup = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

// Pass the current number to the push-up Counter activity.
beginPushup.putExtra(TOTAL_DONE, Total);

// Start mainActivity.
startActivity(beginPushup);
}
```

`TextUtils` is a class provided in Android Framework.
This will check for if the content is not empty and also digits only. You can obviously omit the digit check if you are sure that only number will be the input of your edit text.

Comment: I really like your answer, because it works :D. But Just a question, if you hadn't used TextUtils would you have been able to achieve the same results.  Personally i had no idea TextUtils existed so i'm reading about it right now. I'm just wondering if without it would someone be able to assign a default integer to a EditText? BTW Thanks for the help. you saved me a lot of head scratches. :D

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the same without TextUtils. First as I did in code, we assign a default value "0" to those variable. Then we need to check for null  like this -  if (insertcountBtn.getText() != null && insertcountBtn.getText().toString() != null). So if condition successful we  parse the number. Same can be done for givencountBtn. To check if the text is only digit - you need to write your own method which will loop through each character of the string to ensure it has only number

Answer (score 0):

Because when your EditText is empty, it has no numerical value.

You can do

```
Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());
```

when the input is blank; there's no Integer value there, because there's nothing at all, so it's going to throw a NumberFormatException.

You can do the following to make sure it has a value (default will be 0 on failure):

```
int insertedcountInt;

try {
    insertedCountInt = Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    insertedCountInt = 0;
}
```

Comment: @blaisejohnny I didn't suggest that. I suggested a try-catch.

Comment: i've edited my post with the use of try and catch. one thing I'm seeing is that the contents of the [Catch] i.e. insertcounted = 0; are deemed redundant because it's never used. this begs the question is it actually defaulting to 0 or is the code waiting for a crash to assign it 0? which isn't what I want. if there were a library that could get the contents of TextView and assign it a default value at the same time i think it'd help sort of like the way `getIntent.getIntExtra(String, default int)` works   -- to this line `insertcountInt = Integer.parseInt(insertcountBtn.getText().toString());`

Comment: There's nothing like that, because that's not how EditTexts work. You can assign the variable directly. But your code isn't doing what I suggested. _Only_ the assignment of the variable should be in the `try` block. Everything else goes below and outside of it.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I tried that first thing, with no luck. I might have not done it properly. Thanks for the suggestions. I appreciate it.

Comment: You also need to apply the same logic to givenCountInt. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Just published the working code in case you still wanted to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are defining editText to check for only interger: you did not put the conditional statement for the cases like if String was entered, if editText is blank, it contains String. Hence, you may want to put something like;

```
String editTextString = String.valueOf(insertcountBtn.getText());
if (editTextString == "") {
    //do something
}
```

Alternatively,

```
String editTextString = insertcountBtn.getText().toString();
if (editTextString == "") {
//do something
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I updated my post with edits that include using the empty string " " detection, still no luck.

Comment: i just reread your post something you should know is that in the xml i deemed it's inputType to number. `android:inputType="number"` . So it's empty, but not a string, would this be categorized as null??

Comment: Even though the input type is integer, if you want to get the editText  text, you will always get it inform of string. Hence, whenever it is empty, you can refer to it has an empty string

Comment: Well, let me give you the use case, wrap all your if statement inside my if statement by checking if (editTextString != "") { // do all your if statements here}

Comment: So, by this, no code will get executed if the editText is blank

Comment: Good point. I completely agree. this response below seems to have made it work. when i get back from lunch i'll still try it this way to make sure i understand. Thanks for the suggestions. ;)